# How do I change mouse drag & drop sensitivity in GNOME 41.3?

Tags: accessibility, gnome-40

I'm getting older and my hands are not as steady. Often, I inadvertently initiate d&d when clicking on links or highlighting text, because I moved the mouse a couple of pixels.

I tried googling but I can only find solutions for previous versions. Also, it looks like dconf has been severely neutered.

Comment: Which Linux distro? Does [this](https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/ubuntu/mouse-drag-threshold.html) apply?

Comment: I use Arch. I have "Settings", not "System Settings", and there is no threshold for d&d under mouse.

Comment: Does he situation improve if you lower the speed?

Comment: No idea. I wouldn't want to lower the mouse speed.